# Listdir path should be a string. But i dont know what to do?

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

im making a program to transfer .nc files to .csv files. This is the error I have and I am unsure how to fix it.

ive googled the issue and I cant find something that fits this, sorry

```
import os,sys
folder =("C:/Users/workexp/Downloads/weather.nc", "r")
for filename in os.listdir(folder): 
   infilename = os.path.join(folder,filename)
   if not os.path.isfile(infilename): continue
   oldbase = os.path.splitext(filename)
   newname = infilename.append('.nc,.csv')
   output = os.rename(infilename, newname)
```

expected to output file in a .csv but im stuck on this issue,
thanks guys

Comment: So make it a string. Right now it is a tuple. Why the `"r"` string in that tuple? This is not a call to `open()`, there is no need for a mode argument.

Comment: E.g. `folder = "C:/Users/workexp/Downloads/weather.nc"`

Comment: Please, refer to the official documentation of the `os` module

Comment: What is meant by `output = os.rename(infilename, newname)`? `os.rename()` won't return anything since it's not documented to have any kind of return value, so `output` is always going to get set to `None`. Did you read the documentation about the `os` module before using it?

Answer (score 1):

Below code takes all the files in the 'Downloads' folder, checks if its has a .nc extension, and changes the filename to .csv

```
import os,sys

folder = "C:/Users/workexp/Downloads"
for filename in os.listdir(folder): 
    if os.path.isfile(filename): 
        file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
        if file_extension == '.nc':
            os.rename(filename,file_name+'.csv')
```

Comment: thanks J.D, my code now tells me I have the wrong directory but ive checked through cmd and properties of the folder that it is the right path. would the code affect this?